# Creating a gridview in Android

Tags: android, gridview

Im trying to create a grid view like the one in [instagram](http://acknowledgement.co.uk/mediauploads/blog/496D72A4-6C69-3A04-EC12-BF111312DC48.png)

using this following code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  {

     static final String[] alphabets = new String[] { 
         "A", "B", "C", "D", "E",
            "F", "G", "H", "I", "J",
            "K", "L", "M", "N", "O",
            "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T",
            "U", "V", "W", "X"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, alphabets);

            // create a RelativeLayout
            RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);

            // define the RelativeLayout layout parameters.
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

            // create a gridview
            GridView gridView= new GridView(this);

            gridView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
            gridView.setNumColumns(4);

            gridView.setMinimumHeight(300);
            gridView.setMinimumWidth(300);
            gridView.setColumnWidth(300);

            gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
            relativeLayout.setPadding(50, 50, 50, 50);
            // Adding the gridview to the RelativeLayout as a child
            relativeLayout.addView(gridView);

            // set the RelativeLayout as our content view
            setContentView(relativeLayout, relativeLayoutParams);



    }
```

the result was like this  [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsmwt.png)
I tried putting height and width but still it was not working. why?.it looks like a rectangle.
Also any Idea how to put a border on it? I need to achieve something like this

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZoOW.png) with a border of a black and same width and column for every element like the one in instagram. sample and tutorials would really help.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Do you need to just show strings or images? did you tried a custom Adapter?

Comment: I just want to know how to control the width and height of the each element. So should i use a custom adapter to set width and height?

Comment: You need to create a custom layout for grid item

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a custom ArrayAdapter and a custom grid item

at your MainActivity class implement the custom ArrayAdapter

```
public static class CustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        private List<String> strings;

        /**
         * 
         * @param context
         * @param resource
         * @param objects
         *            your strings to show
         */
        public CustomArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource,
                List<java.lang.String> objects) {
            super(context, resource, objects);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        /**
         * Another constructor that takes Array instead of List
         * 
         * @param context
         * @param resource
         * @param objects
         *            your strings to show
         */
        public CustomArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource,
                String[] objects) {
            super(context, resource, objects);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View gridItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_view_item, parent, false);
            TextView tv = (TextView) gridItem.findViewById(R.id.item);
            tv.setText((CharSequence) strings.get(position));

            return gridItem;

        }

    }
```

and at res/layout add the custom grid item layout named "grid_view_item.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/item_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item"
        android:textColor="#FFDDFF99"
        android:layout_width="200dp" 
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:text="Item" />


</LinearLayout>
```

you can change the width and height attributes as you need. use margin attribute to separate items from each others